# RegExp check if it's a number while it's not empty

Tags: regex, vbulletin

I'm using vbulletin and I can set to custom fields regexp.

I've created a custom field that are userids and only accepts numbers, so the regexp I'm using is:

```
\d+
```

But I need to allow it to be empty. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\d*
```

where * indicates 0 or more digits

Answer (score 1):

Then use this:

```
\d*
```

This means zero or more digits. Zero digits naturally means it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your framework wraps it with the appropriate anchors, just transform that to

```
\d*
```

which matches any number of digits, including 0 digits.

```
/^\d*$/
```

would be better if nothing is anchoring that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change this plus (1 or more) to a star (0 or more).